# x,y,z polar coordinates in a sphere

Tags: math, polar-coordinates

I am currently using the following math to get the x,y,z coordinates with an assumed Hypotenuse of 150 and my known yaw pitch and roll.

```
float zPos = (float)Math.tan(Math.toRadians(rmPitch-90))*150;
float xPos = (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90-rmYaw))*150;
float yPos = (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rmYaw))*150;
```

**Assuming a viewer is standing at 0,0,0 and looking up at P.  Q is 150 units away and i know the yaw and pitch of the view);**

my math seems to work fine until i my pitch gets closer to straight up and down, at which point i realize that x and y need to take into account z in some manner..  please help

[image: Assumine a viewer is standing at 0,0,]

Comment: Could you not turn this into a purely mathematical question, and ask it on math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: sorry, did not think there was an issue with posting it here and tagging it as math, polar-coordinates

Comment: If someone can answer, more power to you. I just think this is more of a math based question than a programming issue.

Comment: Did you look at spherical coordinates on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to think about this is to think about a unit circle embedded in the plane containing P and the z axis. There, the vector Q is one side of the triangle, and PQ is the other. So, armed with that picture in your head:

First, z should be `cos(pitch)`, not `tan(pitch)`. Then, to correct x, y for the pitch, multiply them by `sin(pitch)`.

Note that this is assuming you did intend for phi/pitch to be the angle between the z axis and the vector (and not the more standard angle between the x-y plane and the vector).

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with Euler angles (i.e. the Azimuth, Pitch, Roll system of coordindates) when pitch is plus/minus 90 degrees.  That seems to be what you're referring to, and its known as [Grimbal Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock#Gimbal_lock_in_applied_mathematics).  I recently asked and then answered a question about this on math.stackexchange.com, so perhaps [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381649/whats-the-best-3d-angular-co-ordinate-system-for-working-with-smartfone-apps) will help.

Comment: i am aware of that sir.. and am actually using rotation matrix and sensor fusion of accelerometer, gyroscope, and compass to generate the matrix,  i just was using eulers extracted from the matirx to store polar coordinates in a data base

Comment: OK good, my comment about Grimbal Lock is simply a reaction to your statement about issues when "pitch gets closer to straight up and down".  In which case I'm not sure what problem you have.  Perhaps you should formulate a little more clearly, e.g. explicitly giving symbols for yaw pitch and roll, and saying what problem you're having. Note that just to represent the location of a point on a sphere, you only need two angles, not three.

Answer (score 0):

Since phi is the angle between P and the z-axis, the z-coordinate should be `rho*cos(phi)`. Similarly x is `rho*sin(phi)cos(theta)`, y is `rho*sin(phi)sin(theta)`

Comment: whats theta? i am assuming rho is length of teal line

Comment: theta is the angle θ in your diagram

Comment: ah, and now i see that the image i posted is actually pointing to φ  in the wrong spot.. instead of it being between z and p im actually getting the angle between p and y

Answer (score 0):

dsharlet,  using tan(pitch-90) seemed to be working how i expected... if i switch to cos i have to make it (pitch+180) but following your advise the following code seems to work.. i must be flipping and axis or something weird.. can you speak a bit to the difference between tan(pitch-90) and cos(pitch+180)

```
float zPos = (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rmPitch+180))*radius;
float xPos = (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90-rmYaw))*(float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rmPitch))*radius;
float yPos = (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rmYaw))*(float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rmPitch))*radius;
```